# CSS/HTML Placing a button on image

Tags: html, css

How do I place a button  at the bottom and center of an image?  I currently have a carousel with multiple images which works fine, but when I try to add a button for navigation  purposes it is positioned outside of the image to the right.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Click Me</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't help you without seeing your CSS. You'll need to be using the right combination of `position: relative` and `position: absolute` with the right elements to achieve what you want.

Comment: @codeth why do you need to see his css for it? No matter what, the css will work the same by using an absoltue positioning and a z-index.

Comment: @tacoshy Sure, but there are classes assigned and therefore clearly existing CSS. To help solve the problem appropriately it is useful to understand what the actual problem is.

Comment: @codeth those are satndard bootstrap classes. they wont interfere with custom css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `position: relative;` ont he wrapping parent then use `position:absoltue;` on the button. you can align it to the bottom by using `bottom: 0;` To cenetr an element in an absoltue positioning you have to use `transform`

```css
div.swiper-slide {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  object-fit: contain;
}

div.swiper-slide > button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="swiper-wrapper">
  <div class="swiper-slide">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400.jpg">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn- success">click me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```